# I have trouble calculating by adding the specific value of each element of the array

Tags: java

I'm sure there is a lot if things missing, but I'm ready to listen and learn. I just cant figure how to count numbers that I put in `system.out.println`.

My code:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {

        int[] m = {-3,12,1,51,2,-21,4,-2,42,0,-6,-56};

        getNumbers(m ); 
    }
    public static void getNumbers(int[]m) {
        for(int i=0; i<m.length;i++) {
            if(m[i]<=12&&m[i]>=0) {     //All positive numbers up to 12 give a special value of 1;
                 System.out.println("+"+1);     

            }else if(m[i]<=99&&m[i]>=13) {      // All numbers from 13 to 99 give special value 2
                 System.out.println("+"+2);

            }else if(m[i]<-10) {        //Negative numbers greater than -10 give a special value of -1;
                 System.out.println("-"+1);

            }else if(m[i]<0&&m[i]>-9) {     //For all other numbers, the specific value is the same as the number itself
                System.out.println(m[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *how to count numbers that i put in system.out.println.* What does that mean. What is your code supposed to do? Be precise. Given example inputs and outputs.

Answer (score -1):

Declaring a variable **globally** and setting its default value to **zero** can help you. 
After all, do not forget to increment it at the line before your first if (**but inside of for**)

If I did not misunderstand you